# How to handle 206 response from AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, video-streaming, aws-api-gateway

I have a use case where I want to send 206 response for a video/mp4 file type from the API gateway. My API gateway is in front of an EC2 instance and the size of the video doesn't exceed more than 2 MB. Currently I am not able to handle the 206 partial response code. 200 is working fine as of now. What changes do I need to make in the API gateway to handle partial response as well?

Here is my API Gateway method response and integration response:

[image]

[image]